# Java Inventory Program, How Do I Recall The Objects That are Created?

Tags: java, object, if-statement

I am stuck on this. I have user input for some information on some products, and I make an if else if statement to declare which type of product it is after the user has inputted. Only issue is that I want to recall the object that is created. It will either be created as drill, wrench, or shovel. But how do I store this information so I can recall it, e.g I want to output the items price, id, type, etc?

```
 System.out.println("Welcome to our hardware shop. We have three items in stock: \n" + "Wrench CMMT12001\n"
            + "Power Drill 12v\n"
            + "Shovel D-Handle\n"
            + "Which product would you like to buy?");
    
    product = keyboard.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("How many items of this product would you like?");
    
    items = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    
    System.out.println("What is the date (00/00/0000) ");
    
    date = keyboard.nextLine();
    
    int dayOfYear = dayOfYear(date);
    
    
    if (product.equals("Wrench CMMT12001")) {
        Products wrench = new Products(productXID, product, productXPrice, "X", items, dayOfYear);
        
    }
    
    else if (product.equals("Power Drill 12v")) {
        Products drill = new Products(productYID, product, productYPrice, "Y", items, dayOfYear);
    }
    
    else if (product.equals("Shovel D-Handle")) {
        Products shovel = new Products(productZID, product, productZPrice, "Z", items, dayOfYear);
    }
    
    else 
        System.out.println("You did not enter a product.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the product outside of the IF query:

```
System.out.println("Welcome to our hardware shop. We have three items in stock: \n" + "Wrench CMMT12001\n"
            + "Power Drill 12v\n"
            + "Shovel D-Handle\n"
            + "Which product would you like to buy?");
    
    product = keyboard.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("How many items of this product would you like?");
    
    items = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    
    System.out.println("What is the date (00/00/0000) ");
    
    date = keyboard.nextLine();
    
    int dayOfYear = dayOfYear(date);
    
    Products selected;
    
    if (product.equals("Wrench CMMT12001")) {
        selected = new Products(productXID, product, productXPrice, "X", items, dayOfYear);
        
    }
    
    else if (product.equals("Power Drill 12v")) {
        selected = new Products(productYID, product, productYPrice, "Y", items, dayOfYear);
    }
    
    else if (product.equals("Shovel D-Handle")) {
        selected = new Products(productZID, product, productZPrice, "Z", items, dayOfYear);
    }
    
    else 
        System.out.println("You did not enter a product.");
        
    }
```

Comment: if you want to save several products you can also use an `ArrayList<Products> listProducts = new ArrayList<>();`